# Handle deep linking with multiple redirection

Tags: android, nginx, redirect

I have an android app. trying to work with deep link with multiple redirection.
1st. Redirection - when i open this url ( `https://www.tiny.com/op/abRh4` ) Nginx redirect this URL to
`http://customdomain.com/internal`

2nd Redirection - this Url (`http://customdomain.com/internal/abRh4`) will automatically(by API) redirect to `https://customdomain.com?screen-no=25&notification=show` (long url)

I finally want to open deep link with `https://customdomain.com?screen-no=25&notification=show`. but android open it with `http://customdomain.com/internal/abRh4`

Anyone suggest how to handle multiple redirection with deep link ( can we handle this multiple redirection into single one by nginx config) ?

these are two different server (1st server -> Nginx redirect, 2nd Server -> From where api hits)

nginx Config

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.tiny.com;
        location /op {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass https://customdomain.com/internal;
    }
}

    //this api will hit when we call http://customdomain.com/internal/abRh4

    @GET
    @Path("/{shortKey}")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
    public Response resolveShortUrl(@PathParam("shortKey") String shortUrlKey) {

        UrlShortenerLogicHelper helper = new UrlShortenerLogicHelper();
        try {
            helper.openConnection();
            URI url = new URI(helper.resolveShortUrl(shortUrlKey));
            // return url like https://customdomain.com?screen-no=25&notification=show
            return Response.temporaryRedirect(url).build();
        } catch(Exception e){}
    }
```

Comment: show some code how do you currenlty implementing deep linking and also `WebView` initialization. if first redirect works, why second one shouldn't...

Comment: @snachmsm add some code. may be this will helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple data tags with in your activity's intent filter

```
<data android:host="www.test.com"
 android:pathPrefix="/op/abRh4"
 android:scheme="https" />

<data android:host="www.myOwnSite.com"
 android:pathPrefix="/shorturl/abRh4"
 android:scheme="https" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Sorry but i change the domain name for more clear explanation. can you please help with this. I add some code also to understand